# Rails error on return render action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails controller I have the line

```
return render action: "new"
```

Phusion Passenger gives me the error

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
```

Why is that?

Comment: Can you give us more information, including the model and the view that the controller is influencing?

Comment: @Chiperific It doesn't influence any model. The controller is just rendering the HTML page with the action `new` to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following syntax for `render` is considered standard in Rails:

```
render :action => "new" # drop the `return`
render :action => :new # can also pass a symbol
```

See also:

```
render :template => 'home/index'
render :file => 'path/to/file'
render :text => 'prints this text'
render :partial => 'home/partial' # typically used in views
```

EDIT:

As the commenter below astutely points out, there's an alternative syntax for hash pairing. However, take caution because it *only* works with Ruby 1.9, so any Rails running on Ruby 1.8 (potentially any release [prior to Rails 4.0](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html)) won't be able to utilize it:

```
render action: "new"
render template: 'home/index'
render file: 'path/to/file'
render text: 'prints this text'
render partial: 'home/partial'
```

Comment: Thanks @zeantsoi a person with 2k points saying I'm right is better than narcotics.

Comment: Happy to get your buzz on. Actually, the distinction between what is/isn't possible in different versions or Ruby is quite important. A lot of documentation just glosses over the subject without highlighting other use cases. New users to Rails are often stymied by this precise issue, particularly when they're working with older versions of Rails.

Comment: Agreed, it's good to be able to recognize the syntactical case options, but dangerous to not know when to use one or the other.